# AngularJS Service into Controller

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, ngresource

I have the following code throwing errors:
My **controller** code:

```
App.controller('SelectCustomerController',
    function SelectCustomerController($scope, $location, $resource, customerService) 
    { //DO STUFF}
});
```

I inject a **service** which looks like:

```
App.factory('customerService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('api/customerAPI')
}]);
```

Service makes a restful call to my MVC webapi Get method.
My **app module** is as follows:

```
var tmPromise, App = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination', 'ngAnimate', 'ngResource'], function () {

});
```

And my Layout where i call the Bundle file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/m")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body style="background-color:x#383838;">
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>

        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/services")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/controllers")  
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/pagination")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

As gathered the Service is added to the layout in the service bundle.

Everything i try from re-arrangeing where the scripts are called etgc produces a new error. this one produces :

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'SelectCustomerController' is not a function, got string

I want to inject my service into my controller, so i may call upon my webapi to get JSON back and bind it to my $scope.list to show.  Many more pages will also be doing similar things all using my webAPI,  But for some reason i cant seem to grasp AngularJS dependency injection in my current implementation.

So whats the issue here? something simple I'm overlooking? if you require additional information please let me know and ill update the question.

UPDATE:1)

Praveen Singh gave an answer to remove the error, however a new error is now happening in my controller logic because of the new way im declaring my controller and its dependency's:

```
$scope.$watch("currentPage + numPerPage", function () {
    var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
    , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

    $scope.filteredTodos = $scope.todos.slice(begin, end);
});
```

this function is part of my pagination on my list I have, the error is:

> $scope.$watch is not a function

Comment: When you bundle, do you minify as well? Because the controller is not minification safe.

Comment: nah nod minify yet. but thanks for that info ill keep that in mind

Comment: please try to restrict your questions to one per post.  If someone were to post a new answer now which addresses your *updated* issue, which answer is more correct? the one that solved the first issue, or the one that solved the second? and also, multiple answers addressing different parts of a question is confusing to others who might have similar issues in the future.

Comment: also, your update is misleading.  The *code* says `$scope.$watch`, but the *error* says `$scope.watch`, which is not the same thing.

Comment: Well the answer provided got rid of one error however created a new one (common occurrence), weather that's because of my code or because of the new change is an update to my question, it still fits the question on my Service into Controller, now we are closer to the solution as it appears to revolve around the way the controller is actually implemented that is the source of the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't the same question anymore, but it is understandable why you want it to be.  However, it doesn't really make sense that you would need to change the controller for the proposed answer to work, and if you really did, then the changes deserve, and require their own attention.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your controller like this:

```
App.controller('SelectCustomerController',
    ['$scope', '$location', '$resource', 'customerService',
    function($scope, $location, $resource, customerService) {
}]);
```

Comment: seems to have got rid of the issue although i had to make some changes to the logic in the controller to compensate.  what was wrong with my original declaration? was working fine till now

Comment: ive updated my question, the new way of declaring breaks my controller logic

Comment: Can you embed a code snippet here? Or maybe add a jsfiddle/plunkr? It'll be easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for controller(myController) where we are adding service dependency as a myService. To add a watch on some parameter remember to add $scope as a dependency. In below controller we are adding watch on watchString. In my case, I am putting watch on drop down value. The service is calling another service in my case for api calls which is common through out my application.

```
(function () {
    var module = angular.module('myModule', [
        'dependant-module-1',
        'dependant-module-2'
    ]);

    module.controller('myController', [
    '$scope', 'myService',
    function ($scope, myService) {

        myService.getData($scope);

        $scope.$watch('watchString', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            //Logic on watch
        });
    }
    ]);

    module.service('myService', [
    'serverDataHelper'
    function (serverDataHelper) {
        this.getData = function ($scope) {
            var params = {
                param1: 1,
                param2: 2
            };
            var myDataPromise = serverDataHelper.getData('api end point', params);

            myDataPromise.then(function (serverResponse) {
                if (serverResponse.data != null) {
                    $scope.myData = serverResponse.data;
                } else {
                    $scope.myData = null;
                }
            });

            //OR
            return myDataPromise;
        };
    }]);

})();
```

You can either return the promise from service OR you can pass scope object as a parameter and assign response data to the scope.

Do let me know if your need further help.